# How do I split an array with 26 different string values, that appear as 1 string on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

```
var alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];

var letters = document.createElement("ul");
letters.innerHTML = alphabet;
// This is to split the array "alphabet" into individual strings
 var separatedLetters = document.getElementById("letters");
 separatedLetters.appendChild(letters);
```

this is the code I used to attempt to split the string,

A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z

and that is how it appeared on my web page, it displays as one whole string instead of each letter being a string.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: try: `alphabet.join("")`

Comment: You're using a `<ul>` but you're not wrapping your items with `<li>`s

Answer (score 0):

Something like the follow? Since you are using an unordered list, I am assuming you would want each character on its own bullet

```js
var alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];

var ul = document.createElement("ul");
 
 for(var i = 0; i < alphabet.length; ++i) {
     var li = document.createElement("li");
     li.innerText = alphabet[i];
     ul.appendChild(li);
 }
 
 document.body.appendChild(ul);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an example:

```js
var alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];

var string = alphabet.join("");// <--- array to string ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

console.log(string);

var alphabet = string.split("");// <--- string to array

console.log(alphabet);
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you should wrap every letter with `li` and append each element to the list.

Additionally, in order not to cause unnecessary reflows, you can utilize [Document.createDocumentFragment()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment)

HTML:

```
<div id="letters"></div>
```

JS:

```
var alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];

var separatedLetters = document.getElementById("letters");

var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

fragment.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));

alphabet.forEach(letter => {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = letter;
    fragment.childNodes[0].appendChild(li);
});

separatedLetters.appendChild(fragment);
```